# wxPython do something when wx.CallAfter ends

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

So i wrote the class Smooth() that with it you can change the size of a wx.Window smoothly - not in one tick, but it more like slides.
It works just fine, except i want the IncreaseWidth() method to return only when the window has reached his full size, but instead it returns immediately after I call it, and the window keeps on sliding.
I need the IncreaseWidth() method to be somewhat blocking until the window finishes growing

I have tried so many things for that to work, i tried to implement the method with wx.Timer, threads, but they all seem to return immediately.
I have also tried to do something like

```
while self.window.GetSize()[0] != self.final:
    pass
```

But it seems to somehow block the timer/thread/callafter, which freezes the whole frame.

Any hints? Thank you

```
import wx
import time
import threading


class Smooth(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, window):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, window, -1,  size = (0,8))
        self.window = window

    def IncreaseWidth(self, width):
        self.mid = width/2 + self.window.GetSize()[0]
        self.final = width + self.window.GetSize()[0]
        self.acc = 1

        self.inc()

    def inc(self):
        if self.window.GetSize()[0] < self.mid:
            self.window.SetSize((self.window.GetSize()[0] + self.acc,     self.window.GetSize()[1]))
            self.acc +=1
            wx.CallLater(30, self.inc)
        elif self.window.GetSize()[0] > self.mid and self.window.GetSize()[0] < self.final:
            self.window.SetSize((self.window.GetSize()[0] + self.acc, self.window.GetSize()[1]))
            self.acc -=1
            wx.CallLater(30, self.inc)
        else:
            return
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is very uncommon to say the least, in the GUI domain. Ideally, you would never want to block the main thread that is responsible for processing GUI events. Why do you need that method to not return immediately? With that set, if you need to detect when the panel reaches max width, just do it within `inc` itself, or raise an event that will be handled elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, it worked out eventually. I just passed the function i wanted to activate to inc()